# Realtime regex pattern replacement in Vue

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I'm very new in Vue and need to validate input. So, in this field should not be Cyrillic symbols, that's why I use .replace method in watchEffect hook. Unfortunately, when I type Cyrillic symbols, they appear in input field, but I want them to remove immediately. Maybe you know how to do it?

```
const incorrectToken = ref(/[А-яёЁ]+/ig);

watchEffect(async() => {
  form.value.token = form.value.token != undefined 
        ? form.value.token.replace(incorrectToken.value, '')
        : '';
})
```

Also I've tried to replace incorrect symbols to ' ' (not to '') and it works - cyrillic symbols changed to spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To block unwanted symbols during typing you could use 'beforeinput' event:

```
<template>
  <input @beforeinput="e => /[А-яёЁ]/.test(e.data) && e.preventDefault()">
</template>
```

https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqrVnIsKNArK01VslKyKUnNLchJLEm1i8lTULDJzCsoLVFwSEpNyy9KBXNsY5RSFWztFPSjL0zQvdh/ceKFxlh9vZLU4hKNVL2UxJJETQU1NYVUvYKi1LLUvBKX1LTE0pwSDc0YJaCJNvpw45VqAfFDKmo=

Answer (score 1):

I would wrote something like that in order to remove space from my text input (I did not test your regExp to remove Cyrillic symbols).
You have the *@input* that triggers the input event by executing the method *updateInput*. Inside the method you can replace the token you search (in my exemple a space) and reassign the value to the input. Normally you just have change the regexp by yours.
Note that you have this very useful website to test your regexp : [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input :value="inputVal" type="text" @input="updateInput" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      inputVal: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateInput(ev) {
      const incorrectToken = /\s/g;
      const inputValue = ev.target.value;
      if (inputValue) {
        ev.target.value = inputValue.replace(incorrectToken, "");
      }
    },
   },
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Side note: I was about to build something like this to clean up numeric input, like removing "$" character, but the much simpler solution was to add `type="number"` attribute to the `<input>` tag. Then the browser just ignores non-numeric characters.

It also causes Vue to apply its `.number` modifier and cast the value to a float. ([Vue3 Modifier docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#number))

There is a `.trim` modifier too if you just want to trim whitespace from the input.